# Cannot update identity column 'scope_local_id'

Tags: azure, syncfx

**Update** I revised my approach to use 1 sync scope per database schema. This eliminated the problem for all schemas except `dbo`. Then I split `dbo` into several sync scopes, which seems to have eliminated the problem in `dbo`. It is not clear to me why having a large number of tables in a single sync scope would lead to this particular error message.

I am using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 to set up synchronization between two databases. I am provisioning the Azure database using the following code:

```
// Set up destination server for sync
var destinationScopeProvisioning = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(DestinationConnection, scope);
if (!destinationScopeProvisioning.ScopeExists(ScopeName))
{
    destinationScopeProvisioning.Apply();
}
```

This code throws an exception after running for several minutes:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbPartiallyProvisionedException' occurred in Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: Cannot update identity column 'scope_local_id'.
```

Ordinarily, this kind of error is caused by a scope that already exists, so I've tried the following three methods (several times) to clean up the scopes and start again:

1. Deprovisioning the scope by invoking `deprovisioning.DeprovisionScope(ScopeName)`
2. Deprovisioning the store by invokeing `deprovisioning.DeprovisionStore()`
3. Dropping and recreating the database.

Unfortunately, none of those worked.